# Is there a separate Java locale for Mandarin and Cantonese?

Tags: java, localization, translation, locale, chinese-locale

I'm trying to use the JDK to get the names of different languages translated into other languages. For example:

```
new Locale("en", "US").getDisplayLanguage(new Locale("en", "US")); // English
new Locale("en", "US").getDisplayLanguage(new Locale("fr", "FR")); // anglais
```

I'd like to do this to get "Mandarin" and "Cantonese", but

```
new Locale("zh", "CN").getDisplayLanguage(new Locale("en", "US")); // Chinese
```

Is there a locale variant I can use to get "Mandarin" and "Cantonese" instead of "Chinese"? Is there another Java library I can use to get the names of languages translated into other languages?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that those are essentially two separate _languages_, how do you expect a _locale_ to differentiate between both?

Comment: @fge I don't know. But, locales do include a language component. Java uses it to translate month names and such. So, is there a way to differentiate?

Comment: Submitted a ticket to Unicode CLDR: http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/8792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code returns "yue" in Java 8 but "Cantonese" in Java 14.

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-yue").getDisplayName()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually Mandarin:

```
new Locale("zh", "CN").getDisplayLanguage(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

But, yes, you get `Chinese`

You can use:

```
Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

for `Chinese (China)`

and

```
Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

for `Chinese (Taiwan)`

and

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-HK").getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

for `Chinese (Hong Kong)`